# GitHub API limit

Tags: php, github, github-api

I have website [iOS Cookies](http://ioscookies.com) where I divide libraries(currently 190) written in Swift into categories. When category is displayed, I'm showing list of it's libraries with number of GitHub stars and description.

Since that number of stars doesn't have to be accurate, I've decided to get it for every library at once with CRON job(once a day). Problem is I'm reaching API limit for some reason:

> You have reached GitHub hour limit! Actual limit is: 5000

Which is quite odd, since there's less then 200 libraries, and for each one it's called only once, like this:

```
// GitHub API
$this->github = new GitHub($page);
// list of libraries stored in .yaml file
$libraries = $this->config->get('plugins.swift-version.libraries');
$arrlength = count($libraries);

$array = Array();   

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    $link = $libraries[$x]['link'];
    $path = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $segments = explode('/', $path);

    $author = $segments[1];
    $repo = $segments[2];

    // actual API calling to get number of stars for library
    $libraries[$x]['stargazers_count'] = $this->github->client->api('repo')->show($author, $repo)['stargazers_count'];     
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just because you only call one function on the `Github` object doesn't mean that it only makes one API call. Try breaking it into two or more smaller jobs and schedule them to run an hour apart to stay under the API limit. Or find a more efficient API client. Or write your own API client.

Comment: Oh, ok. makes sense. I'll try write my own client.

Comment: Especially with automatic pagination in clients can exceed you limit easily. In addition to preventing unnecessary calls there is a way to increase the rate limit for unauthenticated calls. https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save you the trouble of writing a full API client, and also because that client is on my to-do list so I need to try out the github API anyway, here's a quick and dirty example which uses precisely one API request:

```
$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/realm/realm-cocoa";

$token = /* https://github.com/settings/tokens */;

$headers = [
    'Authorization: token ' . $token,
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
]);

$foo = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($foo['description'], $foo['stargazers_count']);
```

Output:

```
string(64) "Realm is a mobile database: a replacement for Core Data & SQLite"
int(5888)
```